# How to ignore intermediary migrations

Tags: entity-framework-core, migration, ef-code-first

Hello i have a database in an initial state `M0`.This database has suffered migration `M1`.I now want to apply migration `M2`.I do not understand why i can't apply `M2` since my database is already in `M1`.It retries to apply `M1` and fails since the modifications are already present.

I understand this is like a state machine and it tries to reapply all the chain.
`M0` -> `M1` -> `M2`
I do not understand how do you go from `M1` to `M2`.More importantly how do you go from `M1` to `M2` if you do not have a migration_history table anymore ( i deleted it in order to get a clean slate).

**TLDR** : Given 3 `migrations` : `M0`,`M1` ,`M2` how do you apply code-migrations if your database already  in `M1`.Could you somehow ignore all the chain up until `M2` ?

Comment: *"if you do not have a migration_history table anymore ( i deleted it in order to get a clean slate)"* Well, you shouldn't do that because that's the only info EF Core has regarding applied migrations, thus the "cunnet" db state. Now you have to restore that table records for `M0` and `M1`.

Comment: So  if i have 3 databases [`d0`,`d1`,`d2`] in states `M0`, `M1` and `M2` all without migration tables , how do i  apply [`M0`,`M1`] over `d0` , and `M2` over `d1`.Even `d2` throws error instead of saying `Already up to date`.